# Can't set Deep linking with react-navigation V3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I tried to implement [Deep Linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html) following the official documentation as reference.

I have finished IOS configuration on XCode.

But when I paste the url `mychat://chat` it opens my `A screen` not `Second` screen.  I tested `initialRouteName: 'Second'` it is working.

So I can't figure out what step I am missing.

Here is my Router.js:

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createStackNavigator, 
  createDrawerNavigator, createTabNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import A from './components/A';
import B from './components/B';
import Second from './components/Second';
import DrawerPanel from './components/DrawerPanel';

const Stack = createStackNavigator({
  A: {
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
      'A Screen': A,
      'B Screen': B
    },
    {
      swipeEnabled: false,
      lazyLoad: false,
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          tabStyle: {
            width: 125,
            height: 50
        },
        scrollEnabled: true 
      }  
    })
  },
  Second: {
    screen: Second,
    // path: 'chat/:user'
    path: 'chat'
  }
},
  {
    initialRouteName: 'A',
    headerMode: 'screen'
  }
);
// combine DrawerPanel
const Router = createDrawerNavigator({
  FirstScreen: {
    screen: Stack
  }
},
{
  contentComponent: DrawerPanel,
  drawerWidth: 200
});

// about Deep linking
const prefix = Platform.OS == 'android' ? 'mychat://mychat/' : 'mychat://';
const SimpleApp = createAppContainer(Router);
const MainApp = () => <SimpleApp uriPrefix={prefix} />;

export default MainApp;
```

My React Native dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.9",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't looked at your code too deeply, but i've been stuck for hours with deep linking using react navigation v3, and haven't gotten it working yet. I bet some step is missing from the documentation.

Comment: I think you could simplify your code for the purpose of this question. First remove all styling/options (`tabBarOptions, swipeEnabled, headerMode, etc.`). Then remove the DrawerPanel, you can use `Stack` as your app container: `createAppContainer(Stack);` ? All your doing is nesting the stack navigator unnecessarily. I really hope you'll get an answer to this :)

Comment: Same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path to '' in the parent of your View, In this case you should rewrite your router like this:

```
const Router = createDrawerNavigator({
  FirstScreen: {
    screen: Stack,
    path: ''
  }
},
{
  contentComponent: DrawerPanel,
  drawerWidth: 200
});
```